# Difference between setmaxidle,setminidle,setInitialSize and setmaxactive pool properties?

Tags: database, tomcat7, connection-pooling

Please explain in detail about pool properties in Tomcat7 mentioned below with examples:
What is the use of keeping connections as idle?

```
setMinIdle()
setMaxIdle()
setMaxActive()
setInitialSize()
```

Answer (score 2):

Considering Apache Tomcat

[setMinIdle()](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/PoolConfiguration.html#setMinIdle%28int%29)

> The minimum number of established connections that should be kept in
>   the pool at all times. The connection pool can shrink below this
>   number if validation queries fail and connections get closed. Default
>   value is derived from getInitialSize() (also see
>   setTestWhileIdle(boolean) The idle pool will not shrink below this
>   value during an eviction run, hence the number of actual connections
>   can be between getMinIdle() and somewhere between getMaxIdle() and
>   getMaxActive()

[setMaxIdle()](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/PoolConfiguration.html#setMaxIdle%28int%29)

> The maximum number of connections that should be kept in the idle pool
>   if isPoolSweeperEnabled() returns false. If the If
>   isPoolSweeperEnabled() returns true, then the idle pool can grow up to
>   getMaxActive() and will be shrunk according to
>   getMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis() setting. Default value is
>   maxActive:100

[setMaxActive()](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/PoolConfiguration.html#setMaxActive%28int%29)

> The maximum number of active connections that can be allocated from
>   this pool at the same time. The default value is 100

[setInitialSize()](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/PoolConfiguration.html#setInitialSize%28int%29)

> Set the number of connections that will be established when the
>   connection pool is started. Default value is 10. If this value exceeds
>   setMaxActive(int) it will automatically be lowered.